# Is there a way to choose which biomes DON'T spawn?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In minecraft I'm using a couple mods which add biomes and, there are a few of them I'd really rather do without. So I was wondering if theres a way to turn these biomes off, or to keep them from generating in a world at all?

Comment: Write your own mod to do it

Answer (score 1):

[Biome Tweaker](http://www.curse.com/mc-mods/minecraft/228895-biometweaker) should give you the possibility to tweak anything you want using scripts (disabling biomes should also be possible, even with modded biomes).

You will probably find examples on how to do that on the [wiki](https://github.com/superckl/BiomeTweaker/wiki) or by googling :)